# Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist

Tags: android, telegram

I read many posts about this issue in stackoverflow and Github but I couldn't solve my problem and still get this error when I run the code:

**Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':TMessagesProj:packageDebug'**

> File 'D:\telegram\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.

I don't know what to do now. please help!

Answer (score 3):

I  just solved this problem by copy and paste the debug.keystore at the selected path.

The debug.keystore of your android studio is in the

> **C:\User\ %USERPROFILE% .android**

then you can find debug.keystore and copy it and paste in :

> **telegram\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj**